# Can SBCL arrays have typed arrays as elements?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Consider this simple example:

```
(deftype image nil '(simple-array single-float (100)))
```

Here we are defining a shorthand for a type that is an array that is holding single floats. Let us try creating one like that:

```
(defparameter tmp
  (make-array 100
              :element-type 'single-float
              :initial-element 0.0))
```

Let's check the type just in case:

```
CL-USER> (type-of tmp)
(SIMPLE-ARRAY SINGLE-FLOAT (100))
```

All good. Let us see if we could have those little arrays in another array, to make the retrieval easier, instead of putting everything into a single dimensional array and ending up having a headache calculating the access indexes.

```
(defparameter image-array
  (make-array 10
              :element-type 'image
              :initial-element tmp))
```

There is no way it is going to fail but checking just in case:

```
CL-USER> (type-of image-array)
(SIMPLE-VECTOR 10)
```

Oops, that is not what we want at all. Seems like this new array defaulted to the default element type:

```
CL-USER> (array-element-type image-array)
T
```

That likely means that the application will now have to type check not just the container array elements, but also the elements of child arrays with all the consequences for the performance. The questions that arises is this:

Is storing typed arrays as array elements in another array possible in SBCL?

**EDIT:** That might be a bit too early to panic though as this returns the right type:

```
CL-USER> (type-of (aref image-array 0))
(SIMPLE-ARRAY SINGLE-FLOAT (100))
```

In that case, why do we get `T` as the element type from `(array-element-type image-array)`?

Comment: As per the discussion below, in short, SBCL reports the elements of the outer array as `T` because inner arrays are reference type. It seems like it reports only primitive types as array elements, while reference types are upgraded to `T`. The type of the inner arrays will be reported correctly.

Comment: You should look at `upgraded-array-element-type`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A bit background what ELEMENT TYPE actually means**

If you give an *element type* to `MAKE-ARRAY` you ask the Common Lisp implementation to create an array with optimized space layout (!) which might be restricted to certain element types. You don't need to get an array for exactly this element type, but an array which is most space efficient in this implementation for this element type.

- for numbers the implementation may have special versions for bits, 8 bit bytes, 16 bit words, 32 bit words and a few more.
- it might have special versions for arrays of characters, like strings
- it might have special versions for one or more float number types

Whether there are more depends on the implementation your are using.

For any element type which has not a special implementation, the element type gets upgraded to `T`. This means that the array can have all kinds of objects as elements and *larger* elements like arrays, strings, structures, CLOS objects, ... will always be stored as a pointer to the object on the heap.

A few examples for a certain implementation:

**Integers**

```
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 1))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 1)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 2))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 2)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 3))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 2)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 4))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 4)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 5))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 4)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 7))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 4)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 8))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 4)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 15))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 4)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 16))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 8)                                                                                                                                                 
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 256))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 16)                                                                                                                                                
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 4423423))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 32)                                                                                                                                                
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 4423423423423))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 64)                                                                                                                                                
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 4423423423423423423423423423423))
T
```

**Characters**

```
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type 'character)
CHARACTER
```

**Floats**

```
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type 'single-float)
SINGLE-FLOAT                                                                                                                                                      
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type 'long-float)
DOUBLE-FLOAT
```

**Array**

```
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type 'array)
T
```

Even if you ask for more specific versions of arrays as elements, you very likely get `T` as an answer.

**When to ask for a special array**

The most important reason is to save space. If you have only bits, the general array can store bits, but a bit vector will save lots of space.

But: operations for arrays with special element types **can** be slower. At runtime in safe code there might be an additonal type check and the operations to change / read elements **might** need slower processor instructions.

**Limitations of Common Lisp arrays**

Thus Common Lisp does not have optimized storage layout for arrays of structures, vectors, CLOS objects, etc. Since there is a pointer for each element stored, access always needs an indirection and there is nothing that will guarantee that these objects are stored in linear order in memory. Stored in linear order are the pointers to them in the array.

Check your implementation whether it has optimized space layout for float (single, double, long, ...) arrays.

**Multi-dimensional arrays**

Common Lisp supports true multi-dimensional arrays with up to `ARRAY-RANK-LIMIT` (ABCL has max 8 dimensions on my ARM, some other implementations support more dimensions). These multi-dimensional arrays can also have specialised element types.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like an XY-problem: you'd better use a multidimensional array of floats:

```
(make-array (list width height) ...)
```

... then you do `(aref matrix row column)` and you don't have to compute indices. When you store an array inside an array, you still need to keep the metadata associated with each arrays, like the type of its elements, because you could be referencing each array from elsewhere. That's why the main array only store references and not raw floats.

Note also that the type that can be stored in an array can be a supertype of the declared type, due to array upgrading: [System Class ARRAY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/t_array.htm).

Comment: I suppose in this case two dimensional array will work better in regards of performance as one would be able to access the values in it directly compared to array-in-array approach that can only hold pointers to child arrays.

Comment: @Werdok Yes (but beware of premature optimization).

Comment: True, the performance difference would not be significant in this case, however I have just remembered why I did not want to use the two dimensional arrays from the start, they do not work all that well with `read-sequence`, `map-into` and the likes. Sticking with array of arrays is probably way to go.

Comment: @Werdok You can also use "array-total-size" and "row-major-aref" to access the array as a flat one; I think it should be possible to use SBCL's generic sequences to manipulate a multidimensional array as a sequence using those functions; this looks like something fun to do.

Comment: You could also make a single-dimensional displaced array to map/read into.

Comment: @jkiiski this is actually something that I considered, displacement arrays appear to be similar to slices in D and those are a godsend. But wouldn't that be the poorest choice from the point of view of performance, especially in cases like neural networks where one would have to instantiate a huge amount of displacement arrays for inputs and weights when doing forward and backward passes?

Comment: @Werdok Yes, for perfomance displaced arrays will lose against manipulating the array directly. For real world usage you should try and profile both approaches to see if the convenience is worth the cost. In most application programming the extra allocation will be negligible, but for performance-sensitive applications it might not be a good idea.

Comment: See also http://melisgl.github.io/mgl-pax-world/mat-manual.html#x-28MGL-MAT-3A-40MAT-MANUAL-20MGL-PAX-3ASECTION-29 for solutions which involve foreign matrices (BLAS, ...)